# This code is working but it is so slow for 10k records. Is there any faster way to bulk insert data into SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, sqlbulkcopy

This code is working. And it is better than saving records row by row, but it is so slow for 10K records. Is there any faster way to bulk insert data into SQL Server?

Adding bulk data into database

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=94.73.148.5;" +
                              "Initial Catalog=YirmibesYazilimMutabakat;" +
                              "User id=id;Password=password;";

    var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection)
    {
        DestinationTableName = "FaturaExcel",
        BulkCopyTimeout = 6000
    };

    var dataTable = copyExcel;
    sqlConnection.Open();

    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);

    scope.Complete();
    sqlBulkCopy.Close();
    sqlConnection.Close();
    sqlConnection.Dispose();
}
```

**EDIT: Added BatchSize**

> bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable); This statement takes 40 seconds. The others just fine. Additionally i could'nt use transaction.

```
 string connectionString ="Data Source=94.73.148.5;" +
                          "Initial Catalog=YirmibesYazilimMutabakat;"               
 using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
 {
   var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
   bulkCopy.BatchSize = 4000;
   bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "FaturaExcel";
   var dataTable = copyExcel;
   sqlConnection.Open();
   bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
   bulkCopy.Close();
   sqlConnection.Close();
   sqlConnection.Dispose();
 }
```

Comment: One alternative I've found to work great: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2008/66554/ though I suspect BulkCopy is probably the quickest here

Comment: thanks for your offer. I'll try.

Comment: SqlBulkCopy and TVPs perform similarly well in my experience. Attention detail to [make sure the DataTable schema matches the table type](http://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-tvp-performance-gotchas/) is important, though. 10K records shouldn't take more than a couple of seconds using either technique unless you have an exceeding show network or overloaded SQL Server.

Comment: I have 20K records and it takes 40 seconds

Comment: Maybe you are right it is about the overloaded SQL server. Because 40 seconds is too much.

Comment: Take a look at the database during the insert using something like `sp_WhoIsActive`. It will tell you what it's waiting for

Answer (score 1):

SqlBulkCopy is already VERY fast.

20k records should not take 40 seconds.

Here is some technique to improve SqlBulkCopy performance:

- Using a BatchSize may increase the performance. For example 4000
- Using the option SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock will increase the performance.

**EDIT: Answer comment**

> I already used SqlBulkCopy. Did i do something wrong

Yes, I know. My point is you will not find anything really faster than SqlBulkCopy for inserting.

> How can i use BatchSize

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, transaction))
{
    // SET BatchSize value.
    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 4000;

    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TheDestinationTable";
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
}
```

Source: http://www.sqlbulkcopy-tutorial.net/batchsize

As said, the BatchSize may or not help. This is a bad practice to let the default batch size value (0 = unlimited) since inserting multiple batches is often faster than inserting 1 million rows at once. In your case, you only have 20k but since it takes 40s, it could worth a try.

> Could it be a situation related to the SQL database

I believe your issue is perhaps more a network issue or something like this. Inserting 20k rows should take less than 1 seconds.

I recommend you to try and benchmark a few "INSERT" statement to check how much time take a database roundtrip. For example by inserting one row. I have seen some people on Azure that inserting one row was taking more than 100ms which is insanely slow.

Comment: I already used SqlBulkCopy. Did i do something wrong? How can i use BatchSize?Could it be a situation related to the SQL database?

Comment: BatchSize sounds so logical. But it is still strangely so slow.

Comment: Did you check single insert time and db load?

Comment: var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
  sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
  watch.Stop();
  var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds; I tried this with one record. it takes 3816 milisecond.

Comment: Did u mean that?

Comment: Could you try to insert with a SQL Command without using SqlBulkCopy to get the time taken? Obviously, 3816ms for one row is not normal

Comment: var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Authors(Fname,Lname)Values('" + _fname + "','" + _lname + "')", cn);
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            watch.Stop();
            var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds; I tried and it takes 1455 milisecond.

Comment: 1.5s to insert one record via SqlCommand is obviously not normal. You need to check why the communication is so bad to the server.